# Storing numbers in a MySQL SET column

Tags: mysql, insert

How should I insert numbers in a SET column? I know that for ENUM it's recommended to not store numbers in ENUM column, and numbers should be insert with ''. 
Is it the same for a SET column? Should be numbers inserted with ''? Like '1','2' or is it fine to insert it like: 1, 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use MySQL's SET and ENUM column types.

Second, your set definition really shouldn't contain numbers. 'One' is OK, '1' will be extremely confusing.

Third, if you insert numerals like `1`, `2`, etc then it will actually insert the n-th member of the set instead of that number, whereas if you insert `'1'` it will insert that member. The difference comes up when you have a set with the following members in that order: `'foo', 'bar', '1', '2'` - if you insert `'1'` it would be the same as inserting a `3`, but if you insert a `1` it'd be the same as `'foo'`.

Bottom line: don't use the SET and ENUM column types.

Comment: Not enough explanation or referencesfor a broad statement like "don't use this feature"

Answer (score 1):

You insert using SET values names and enclose them in single quotes and separate them with commas.

Minimalistic example from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html):

```
CREATE TABLE myset (col SET('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'));
INSERT INTO myset (col) VALUES ('a,d,d,s');
```

Answer (score -1):

Number should insert like 1 ,2 ,3.
This consider as character if you put into single quote like '1','2'.